# Table and FindRoot of a 2 variable function of x and t : cos(x + 3t)

Tags: functions, warning-messages, list-manipulation, variable

I am trying implement `mathematica` commands: `Table` and `FindRoot`, of a 2 variable function `cos(x + 3t)` to find all the `x` values where the cosine function meets the `x` axis, i.e. `cos(x + 3t) == 0`, and the times, `t`, when this happens. Can someone indicate how this can be accomplished, or if it is possible within `mathematica`?

```
xInit = 0;
xmin = -4 Pi;
xmax = 4 Pi;
dx = 0.1;

tmin = 0;
tmax = 10;

Astep[x_, t_] := Cos[x + 3 t]

Union[Table[x /. FindRoot[Astep[x, t] == 0, {x, xInit, xmin, xmax}, {t, 0, tmin, tmax}], {xInit, xmin + dx, xmax - dx, dx}], SameTest -> Equal]
```

The error messages are:

```
FindRoot::nveq: The number of equations does not match the number of variables in FindRoot[Astep[x,t]==0,{x,xInit,xmin,xmax},{t,0,tmin,tmax}].

ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[Astep[x,t]==0,{x,xInit,xmin,xmax},{t,0,tmin,tmax}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::nveq will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Table[{t, x /. NSolve[{Astep[x, t] == 0, -4 Pi < x < 4 Pi}, x]}, {t,1, 10}]
(* {{1, {-10.854, -7.71239, -4.5708, -1.4292, 1.71239, 4.85398, 7.99557,11.1372}}
, {2, {-10.7124, -7.5708, -4.4292, -1.28761, 1.85398,4.99557, 8.13717, 11.2788}},...}*)
```

Comment: Thank you Ulrich Neumann, that solved it!