# Table and FindRoot of a two-variable interpolated function

Tags: function-construction, warning-messages, list-manipulation, interpolation

I am having difficulty solving for the roots of the following interpolating function:

```
ndsolve = NDSolve[ pdes3, {pGb, pXb, pYb}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, {t, 0, T},
  MaxStepSize -> 3/100, MaxSteps -> 75000 ]
```

How can I find the roots of `pXb == 0`, near `x = 0`, along with time?  Here is what has been tried so far:

I asked a question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200731/table-and-findroot-of-a-2-variable-function-of-x-and-t-cosx-3t), about using [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) and [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) for a 2 variable function. The answer was helpful but used `NSolve` instead of `FindRoot`. This test program for `Cos(x + 3t)`, was to aid in a further problem. The question I want to ask here involves finding the roots of an interpolation function `pXb` (values of distance, `x` and time, `t` for function `pXb == 0`), using a function called `ndsolve`, shown above.

Main code is shown here, with the above expression at Line 220.

This [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200731/table-and-findroot-of-a-2-variable-function-of-x-and-t-cosx-3t), was used to create a `FindRoot` expression:

```
xInit = 0;
xmin = -4 Pi;
xmax = 4 Pi;

tmin = 0;
tmax = 10;

Astep[x_, t_] := Cos[x + 3 t]

Union[Table[{t, x /. FindRoot[Astep[x, t] == 0, {x, xInit, xmin, xmax}]}, {t, tmin, tmax}], SameTest -> Equal]
```

**output:** `{{0, 0.}, {1, -7.71239}, {2, -4.4292}, {3, -1.14602}, {4, -1.00443}, {5, -0.862833}, {6, -0.72124}, {7, -0.579648}, {8, -0.438055}, {9, -0.296462}, {10, -0.15487}}`

However, in this test code, the output did not show all the roots, only one root for each time increment.

By using the answer by [Ulrich Neumann](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200731/table-and-findroot-of-a-2-variable-function-of-x-and-t-cosx-3t), I adapted the main code to include:

```
Table[{t, x /. NSolve[{pXb[x,t] /. ndsolve == 0, -1 <= x <= 2}, x]}, {t, 1, 10}]
```

giving error messages:

```
ReplaceAll::reps: {{{pGb->InterpolatingFunction[{{<<2>>},{<<2>>}},{5,5,1,{<<2>>},{<<2>>},0,{<<2>>},0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{{<<667>>},{<<398>>}},{Developer`PackedArrayForm,{<<265069>>},{<<795204>>}},{Automatic,Automatic}],pXb->InterpolatingFunction[{{<<2>>},{<<2>>}},{5,5,1,{<<2>>},{<<2>>},0,{<<2>>},0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{{<<667>>},{<<398>>}},{Developer`PackedArrayForm,{<<265069>>},{<<795204>>}},{Automatic,Automatic}],pYb->InterpolatingFunction[{{<<2>>},{<<2>>}},{5,5,1,{<<2>>},{<<2>>},0,{<<2>>},0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{{<<667>>},{<<398>>}},{Developer`PackedArrayForm,{<<265069>>},{<<795204>>}},{Automatic,Automatic}]}}==0} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.
```

How can I use `FindRoot` to obtain all the roots of the `pXb` interpolating function along the `x` axis, at time increments of `t`?

Sated again, the basic problem is to find `x` values of `pXb` (also called `phi_X`) at zero, and then determine the midpoint, `x`, either side of `phi_X` nearest the origin, for a range of time `t`. This is to measure the movement of the resultant Soliton plot shown in the figure below.

[image]

The code has been adapted here to run quickly and shows my notes here (commented out code), for including the `Table` and `FindRoot` commands; and the `ndsolve` is shown here.

Comment: Please give a short example of your problem. You cannot expect people to check 250 lines of code I think.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information. I hope that's helpful in explaining it more fully.

Comment: The search of "2 variables" brings "two-variable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running your code use

```
{PGb, PXb, PYb} =NDSolveValue[pdes3, {pGb, pXb, pYb}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, {t, 0, T},MaxStepSize -> 3/100, MaxSteps -> 75000]
```

instead of `ndsolve`.

`ContourPlot`shows you the possible solutions of `PXb[x,t]==0`

```
ContourPlot [PXb [x, t] == 0  , {x, -L/4, L/4}, {t, 0, 10} ,MaxRecursion -> 4, FrameLabel -> {x, t}]
```

[image]

The solution pairs {t,x} can be evaluated using `FindRoot`

```
tx=Table[{t, x /. FindRoot[ PXb [x, t] == 0, {x, 0, -L/4, 0} ]}, {t, 0,T}]
(*{{0, 0.}, {1, -2.4937}, {2, -2.57681},...}*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Ulrich Neumann, for helping me solve this.